# how can I install win32con?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32con, python-winshell

I'm trying to use winshell to generate a url shortcut file,
so I did:
`pip installed winshell`

However on line 30 of the `winshell.py` file it requires the module `win32con` : my understanding is that `win32con` is apart of `pywin32`, which is already installed.

The specific error I get when trying to import `win32con` is:

```
(base) C:\Users\deana>pip install win32con
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32con (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32con
```

I've found a few references online and on stack exchange but nothing.
running windows 11.

Comment: As you said, it is a part of `pywin32` and you also said it was already installed.  Just `import win32con`.  If `pywin32` is *not* installed, then `pip install pywin32`.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
pip install pywin32
```

Happy to help.

Comment: says already installed, see question

Comment: @marlon-d-alessandra : I noticed that you're using a virtual environment. Did you install pywin32 in the virtual environment and activate the virtual environment when you install winshell?